Power automate connection to Azure Storage account with public endpoint restriction
Can power automate cloud connect to a storage account with public end point restricted with Firewall rules (Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses)?
Thanks

Can you add more points which you tried?

According to this MS-Document In Power Automate and Power Apps we don't support connecting to storage accounts that are behind firewalls.

We have not tried anything so far.  We have other SAAS services for which the public endpoint firewall restriction is implemented with the Vnet ids. So was wondering if it is feasible for Power automate as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Tinju Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?

Hi @Venkatesan, thanks for the input. Need to try out the recommended solution.

Is the below approach worked for you?


Can power automate cloud connect to a storage account with public end point restricted with Firewall rules (Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses)?

According to this MS-Document,

Power Automate Cloud does not currently support connections to Azure Storage Accounts that have firewall restrictions enabled (e.g., limiting access to selected virtual networks and IP addresses only).
This means that if a storage account requires network-based security, it cannot be accessed directly from Power Apps or Power Automate.

As work around you can use an Azure API Management (APIM) gateway or an Azure Function as an intermediary.
In APIM, you can configure APIM with a private endpoint to access the storage securely. use  APIM policies for authentication and authorization. Finally, create a custom connector in Power Automate to interact with APIM, which will forward requests to the storage account.
In Azure function, same as APIM process instead APIM policy you can use  Azure AD for authentication and authorization.
Reference:
connector - PowerApps: Access Azure Storage Account only accessible from selected vNet and IP address ranges - Stack Overflow by nickdoesstuff
